# VSCODE: Terminal opens when I press run

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press run button at top right corner terminal opens and does nothing. I have changed settings unknowingly. I have tried uninstall, deleting files in appdata and reinstall. I also tried restting settings to default But no use. This happens with python and Java. I want it to run in default way where it opens the internal terminal below and runs it.
[image]

setting.json file

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "editor.unusualLineTerminators": "auto",
    "launch": {
    
        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": []
    }
}
```

Comment: the Python extension does not know the directory to change to because there is no `launch.json` because you don't have a workspace open. Use menu `File | Open folder`

Comment: @rioV8 I tried thats not problem. Well before I used to with opening work space

Comment: what is your `.vscode/launch.json` file?

Comment: @rioV8 I have put on question please check

Answer (score 0):

Press 'Windows-Key"+R , and enter %APPDATA%\Code\User

And delete 'setting.json' at this location.

> Then restart you computer.

Comment: That didn't work. I have tried  deleting setting.json before

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the problem was with legacy console option. I just disabled it now in works!